# How to add a Text Footer to an Altair graph?

Tags: python, altair

It is possible to add a footer to an Altair graph?

I've been looking for options but I only found the `text`and `subtitle` title properties().

Here's my plot code (from a concatenated graph)

```
mobility_colima.configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=7,
    titleFontSize=7
).properties(
    title={
        "text":["Movilidad en CDMX"],
        "subtitle": ["Jay Ballesteros (@jballesterosc_)"],
    }
)
```

Here's the output where I'll like to add a footer:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no footer property for Altair charts, but you can abuse the title property to add a footer. It might look something like this:

```python
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(100)
source = pd.DataFrame({
  'x': x,
  'f(x)': np.sin(x / 5)
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='f(x)'
).properties(
    title=alt.TitleParams(
        ['This is a fake footer.', 'If you want multiple lines,', 'you can put them in a list.'],
        baseline='bottom',
        orient='bottom',
        anchor='end',
        fontWeight='normal',
        fontSize=10
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to add this footer without sacrificing the original title? I mean the following lines: ``` properties(
    title={
        "text":["Movilidad en CDMX"],
        "subtitle": ["Jay Ballesteros (@jballesterosc_)", "Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del COVID-19 Community Mobility Reports de Google. (Datos del 15 de febrero al 15 de noviembre de 2020"],
    }
)```

Comment: Sure, you can do this by wrapping your chart in a `concat`. For example: `alt.concat(my_chart_with_title).properties(title=...)`

Comment: @jakevdp -  Since objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within ConcatChart, how can we configure both a title and a footnote?